# Array of functions in swift (Output needs to be explained)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I was working with swift and got a question from somewhere but didn't understand what output will I get while running the function.

```
import UIKit

var i = 0
var closureArray : [() -> ()] = []

for _ in 1...5{
    closureArray.append {
        print(i)
    }
    i += 1
}
```

what will I get when I will type:-

```
closureArray[0]()
```

I know the answer but i want to know the explanation behind it.

Comment: The [Swift Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) explains it neatly. Check it out.

Comment: The closure body, **print(i)** for all the closures, will be executed (and i value evaluated) only after calling it (nothing new here). The key is that you are calling the closure after the loop so at that point the value of the **var i** is **5** and that's why all the closures body will have the same result "5".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are appending functions body to `closureArray` with no return type as the function type has no input parameters and no return type.

So only `closureArray` will contains 5 blocks of functions.

Each element is itself a function with only one `print` operation which will print the array index. But if these are called after the `for` loop these always print the latest value of `i`

So `closureArray[0]()` will call the 0th indexed function that will print only "5" as the latest value of `i` is 5 and will return void.

Explanation is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

This will always print `5` because you have defined a global variable, after traversing through the loop `i=5`. and after the loop, you are calling closure. which will always print 5. no matter the index of `closureArray`.

The value of `i` is only evaluated after calling closure.

Read Auto closure chapter swift4 guide:

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html

if you put closure calling inside for loop then it will print normally 'i' value 
i.e 0,1,2,3,4

```
for _ in 1...5{
    closureArray.append {
        print(i)
    }
    closureArray[0]()
    i += 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The functions appended in the `closureArray` is `print(i)` every time and the value of i is incremented for each iteration. The functions appended return void. So when you see the value of `closureArray[0]()` after each iteration it would print each value of `i` (i.e. 1 to 5) and return **void**. If you see the value of `closureArray[0]()` after the loop has executed it would return **5** and **void**. Moreover, for an array index, it would return the same value.